# Delete an element in a tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

What I want to do is to take a binary search tree, and an element, and then remove it from the tree
(if it is present).

Here is my code:

```
data BinaryTree a = Null | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
  deriving Show

type BSTree a = BinaryTree a

treeDelete :: (Ord a) => (BSTree a) -> a -> (BSTree a)
treeDelete a btree = case btree of
  Null -> Null
  Node Null val Null
     |a==val -> Null
     |otherwise -> Node Null val Null
  Node left val right
         |a==val-> Node left Null right
         |otherwise -> (treeDelete a left) val (treeDelete a right)
```

Comment: What's the point of defining `BsTree`?

Comment: The problem is that `Null` is not a value of type `a`; it's a value of type `BinaryTree a`. Your definition of `BinaryTree` doesn't allow you to just put "holes" in the tree. If you remove the root of a tree, you have to replace it with a value from one of the two subtrees, which will require some modification of that subtree as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Change you data structure definition as

```
data BinaryTree a = Null | Node (BinaryTree a) (Maybe a) (BinaryTree a)
```

which is a simplified trie keyed by `[Bool]`.

2. Define a rotation behavior (like in Balanced Tree) to fill in the blank after delete.  The rotation is not unique.  For example, for the lazy Map in the container package, the deletion of a balanced tree is defined as:

```
data Map k a  = Bin Size k a (Map k a) (Map k a)
              | Tip

type Size     = Int

delete :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Map k a
delete = go
  where
    go :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Map k a
    go !_ Tip = Tip
    go k t@(Bin _ kx x l r) =
        case compare k kx of
            LT | l' == l -> t
               | otherwise -> balanceR kx x l' r
               where l' = go k l
            GT | r' == r -> t
               | otherwise -> balanceL kx x l r'
               where r' = go k r
            EQ -> glue l r
```

`balanceR`, `balanceL` and `glue` are rotation to balance depth in a balanced tree.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html

Comment: Replacing one unknown (deleting an item) with another (defining a rotation behavior) isn't very helpful.

Comment: Agree, I think I shall update my answer with example code from containers later.  Thank you for amending my answer.